# Get the results of Code inspections

Tags: .net, cmd, resharper, static-code-analysis

I installed `Resharpers command line tool`.Then I tried

`InspectCode SolutionFile.sln > errors.txt`.

The output in errors.txt is

```
JetBrains Inspect Code 9.1 
Running in 64-bit mode, .NET runtime 4.0.30319.34014 under Microsoft Windows     NT 6.2.9200.0
Solution-wide analysis is DISABLED
Running inspections
Inspecting <Project>\Common\Bindable.cs
Inspecting <Project>\Common\Converter.cs and so on..
```

**How can I convert the output `.tmp` files generated into an `html` file from `command prompt`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `/o=` command line parameter to specify where the output file is written. By default, it goes to the `%TEMP%` folder. This output file is an xml file that you can then analyse or convert with a stylesheet. More details on the command line options [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode).

Comment: Is there any command line option available to convert this xml into an html file.

Comment: No, you need to apply your own stylesheet to produce html. The tools were intended to allow plugging into CI solutions other than TeamCity, and they'll each want to display things differently, so there's no common html output. It might be a nice feature, though - you can add a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: In my question there is a line `Solution-wide analysis is DISABLED`. What is that? Will it affect my output?

Comment: I think it means that it's not running solution wide analysis, just checking each file in turn. This means you won't get warnings such as unused public methods - these require solution wide analysis to be enabled so that ReSharper can see that no-one in the solution calls these methods. So, in that respect, it will affect your output - you're likely to get more with solution wide analysis enabled.